# VS Code Development Containers with relative folders above root folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, devcontainer

I am struggling with my VS Code setup in connection with the container extension.

My project structure has one project folder and several libraries on the same level (i.e. libraries are *not* subfolders of my project folder). The key thing is that I would like to save all config files in my project folder so the information how to bring up the project is version controlled with the project.

If I specify the `workspace` file as follows (using relative paths) and open the workspace file, things work fine locally.

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "path": "../library1"
        },
        {
            "path": "../library2"
        },
    ]
}
```

However, when I try to bring this in my development container, I get the error message:

```
The workspace cannot be opened in a container. Folder c:\..\library1 is not a subfolder of shared root folder c:\..\project.
```

I could pull the project definition (and `devcontainer.json` file) one level up but then they are not under source control of my project folder.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a design limitation.  Even if you set the workspace root of the container accordingly, it still doesn't seem to be possible to reference workspace folders outside of the folder containing the workspace definition.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/387

> To start, we could support an open workspace command that is the
>   equivalent of doing "Open Folder in Container" followed by "Open
>   Workspace" but does not resolve these two limitations. Specifically it
>   would:
>
> Look for a .devcontainer/devcontainer.json or .devcontainer.json file
>   in the same folder as the .codeworkspace file. Mount this folder into
>   the container and open the workspace. **The .codeworkspace file would
>   only be able to reference sub-folder**s.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022 - now using the updated [Dev Containers extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers).

I have the following structure (in short):

```
├───deployment
├───documentation
├───service1
│   ├───.vscode
│   └───sources
├───service2
│   ├───.vscode
│   └───sources
└───workspace
    ├───acme.app.code-workspace
    ├───.devcontainer
    └───devcontainer.json
```

**acme.app.code-workspace**

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "name": "Service 1",
            "path": "../service1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Service 2",
            "path": "../service2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Deployment",
            "path": "../deployment"
        },
        {
            "name": "Documentation",
            "path": "../documentation"
        }
    ]
}
```

**devcontainer.json**

Nothing really of interest here.  Just put in what you need.

```json
{
    "name": "Docker in Docker",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bullseye",

    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-in-docker:2": {
            "version": "latest",
            "enableNonRootDocker": "true",
            "moby": "true"
        },
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/kubectl-helm-minikube:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1": {
            "version": "3.11"
        }
    }
}
```

So when you start the container, all should be fine.

[image: vscode in docker container]

The only drawback - whether the prompt is acceptable when starting the devcontainer:

[image: prompt]

This **does not work** if I bring the `.devcontainer` folder into it's own workspace folder.

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "path": "../.devcontainer"
        },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symlink from the logical root (= where your .code-workspace file is) of your workspace to the target .devcontainer directory in a sub-project of the workspace. Then it looks like you have the .devcontainer folder in the logical root of your workspace. VSC can then open the devcontainer definition inside a devcontainer in the normal way

### Linux and similar

Do this in logical root of multi sub-project workspace

```
ln -s TARGET-SUB-PROJECT-PATH/.devcontainer
```

### Windows

This also works on Windows, using the `mklink` command which is available in Cmd shell (built-in to CMD, not a separate command, so you only have access to it in CMD). On Win 10 you need to be in an Administrator CMD to make a symlink. On Win 11, you do not need admin for this.

Do this in the logical root of multi sub-project workspace

```
mklink /D .devcontainer TARGET-SUB-PROJECT-PATH\.devcontainer
```

---

PS. *Completely unnecessary to read, unless you are interested*. Here is more about how I use multi-project workspaces. I don't think what I do is a fit for lots of use cases, but it may be helpful if you are  thinking this through for the first time.

- I put my current projects in a dedicated docker volume (not the user home directory in the container). This way, I have access to all my current projects from whatever dev container I happen to be in. I mount this workspace volume in all my dev containers via `workspaceMount` setting in `devcontainer.json`.
- This approach helps me when I need to assemble a new multi-project workspace via a .code-workspace file. I can start from within a running dev container in a single project, cd to the volume where I have all the projects and create a new workspace folder with a new .code-workspace file, quickly gathering a couple of projects together via that workspace file. In the same directory as the workspace file, I can link to a .devcontainer directory in a sub-project of choice.
- Once I have a new workspace, I change the devcontainer.json in the targeted sub-project to target the new workspace folder as its workspace folder (see `workspaceFolder` below). I have something like the two lines below in all my `devcontainer.json` files. The first line is identical in all my dev containers (the volume I use). The second line can vary per dev container. PARTICULAR-MULTI-PROJ-WORKSPACE-PATH is where both the VSC workspace file is and also where the symlink to a .devcontainer in one of the subprojects is.

```
    "workspaceMount": "source=workspace-volume,target=/workspace,type=volume",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/PARTICULAR-MULTI-PROJ-WORKSPACE-PATH"
```

- From the new workspace root folder, I can now do a VSC `Dev Containers: Rebuild Container` command. It will build a bit, then reopen everything via the multi-project workspace.
- In projects that are not part of a larger workspace, the workspace folder in devcontainer.json would remain pointing within the project, i.e., to the root of the project itself.
- The sub-project I target (whose .devcontainer folder I target) is usually the project consuming all the other stuff (all the other projects). And it's usually chronologically the youngest, the specific thing I am currently working on--where all the other sub-projects are prior work or downloaded code. But I may need to both consult and tweak those other projects as I go--which is why the multi-project workspace is so helpful. Example: I probably have done the work to set up the infrastructure before this, such as defining a dev k8s cluster on which my POC will be running. (That is hard work, and best to re-use over and over).
- In my case, I usually don't source control the workspace stuff, which is why I am pointing at a devcontainer.json in a sub-project. The workspace definition itself does not fit with the purpose of any of my sub-project repos. Example: repo A defines some infrastructure, repo B has an app to deploy, repo C has a different tier to deploy for serving apis for the app. I might use repo A in another workspace as well. Maybe I am currently working on B or C, or both. So I don't think of the workspace as belonging to any of the specific repos. It's just a convenience, letting me view and work with multiple things together. That's why I don't source control it.
- So, I have this one point of awkwardness. I am leaking knowledge of the workspace into a subproject in that one line in the devcontainer.json file in the targeted sub-project where I set the `workspaceFolder`. In my particular workflow, I do mostly POCs, so I am in pure early development mode and I am not yet sharing the fruits of my work. So I am ok with this slight bit of mess. Once I have to share, I would not leave the `workspaceFolder` that way. At that point, I have to evaluate whether the workspace setup is something that needs to be shared. If so, I need a new, separate git project to share the setup. Then the devcontainer concerns, etc., logically need to move to this new project.
- But when I am in POC mode, I don't yet know what sharing will look like (or whether I will share anything--maybe I am just exploring). I don't know whether the workspace needs to survive as a shared thing, so I optimize for myself and treat the workspace as a transient convenience until I know otherwise.